Problem when trying to fetch data from the Fetch API. Empty parentheses arrive before clicking in the console
I'm trying to get a data from fetch API, but my result is empty before I click on result in console. And I couldn't manage this data in my app. I don't have something, problem with asynchronous getting data from fetch.
I tried to use other asynchronous methods to receive data, but all to no avail.



Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

It's not clear to me the overall structure that you're trying to build, but you certainly wouldn't be able to rely on asynchronous operations being completed in a constructor.

TL;DR - you're using asynchrony wrong. The data is retrieved asynchronously - so the console.log occurs before the object is later populated, however the console evaluates the content of that object when you click on it - therefore it looks like it has data, yet it doesn't at the time you console.log it ... to verify console.log(structuredClone(this._data)) and note how it DOESN'T get populated later

read this and this

If the actual method that gets remote data is async you need to make every method in your stack async and then await each return value. That's why you are seeing the default value. For example...
// constroller.js
async getDataFromModel() {
  this._data = await model.getData();
  console.log(this._data);
}
// weatherModel.js
async getData() {
  return await this.getPosition();
}

